# How to add arguments in custom bash commands?

Tags: bash, function, arguments, alias

I am trying to add custom variable in a bash script alias command and not able to do it

I added the following in `.bash_profile` file

```
alias mvdb='mv ~/dbs/aw ~/dbs/aw-$1'
```

In the command line I am trying to run a script

```
mvdb "2017OCT20"
```

I want the folder named `aw` to be renamed as `aw-2017OCT20` when I run command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a job for a function.

```
mvdb() {
    mv ~/dbs/aw ~/dbs/aw-"$1"
}
```

Comment: i added the alias to bash profile with a single line code, `alias mvdb='mv ~/dbs/aw ~/dbs/aw-$1'` So, Can I write the function that you had mentioned directly in .bash_profile, or do i need to create a new file containing only this function